# SELECT all values from one table with reference to another table but the value there is missing

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables (in reality I have multiple tables but for this problem I need only two). I want to select ALL values from one table where a condition is met. The condition is - select all those values which are not referenced in the second table. To be more clear: imagine you have one table with your friends name, address, and phone number. They were also meant to give you their birthday, which you want to store in the second table. Now you want to find all those who have NOT given you their birthday yet. So you want to list all the information from one table where the values related to them in the second table is null.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT A.value1, A.value2, A.value3
FROM Table A, Table B
WHERE A.PrimaryKey=B.PrimaryKey
AND B.value1 = NULL;
```

Comment: Can you show the dummy data so that we can help why it is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using implicit `inner join` syntax, when you need a `left join`:

```
SELECT A.value1, A.value2, A.value3
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
   ON A.PrimaryKey=B.PrimaryKey
WHERE B.value1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: @amdixon, you're right, I blindly copied. Table names were not mentioned by OP

Comment: So Left Join takes into account the entire first table, and then only looks at the crossover between the first and second table and ignore all those values from the second table where this crossover does not exist?

Comment: @BystrikOndica, see http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php. You may like to search for an SQL tutorial as well, this is pretty basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

Use left join for your query as following :

```
SELECT A.value1, A.value2, A.value3
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.PrimaryKey=B.PrimaryKey
WHERE B.value1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: from table A should be from A

Comment: copied from your above query, check now